# Changing directory using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, bash, child-process

Is there a way to change directory using a NodeJS process?

I want something like this:

```
/$ node_cd /path/to/directory
/path/to/directory$ _
```

Basically the same effect as 'cd'.

I tried to do it with child_proccess exec but didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe bash can help?

Make it a bash alias/function:
`root@/tmp$ node_cd(){ cd /path/to/directory; ./helloword;  }`

```
root@/tmp$ node_cd
Hello World
root@/path/to/directory $
```